# Usar eventListeners en un componente vue2

Tags: javascript, vue.js, google-maps-v3

Soy nuevo en esto del desarrollo web pero el caso es que estoy intentado crear una aplicación web que contiene un mapa de google. Siguiendo algunos tutoriales he creado este componente:

```
<template>
  <div class="google-map" :id="mapName"></div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: 'google-map',
  props: ['name'],
  data: function () {
    return {
      mapName: this.name + "-map",
      markerCoordinates: [{
        latitude: 41.3850639,
        longitude: 2.1734035
      }, {
        latitude: 41.4023337,
        longitude: 2.2015487
      }, {
        latitude: 41.3947209,
        longitude: 2.1761431
      }],
      map: null,
      bounds: null,
      markers: [],
      label: {text:'A', color: "white"}
    }
  },
  mounted: function () {
    this.bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
    const element = document.getElementById(this.mapName)
    const mapCentre = this.markerCoordinates[0]
    const options = {
      center: new google.maps.LatLng(mapCentre.latitude, mapCentre.longitude)
    }
    this.map = new google.maps.Map(element, options);
    this.markerCoordinates.forEach((coord) => {
      const position = new google.maps.LatLng(coord.latitude, coord.longitude);
      const marker = new google.maps.Marker({ 
        position,
        map: this.map,
        label: this.label
      });
    this.markers.push(marker)
      this.map.fitBounds(this.bounds.extend(position))
    });
  }
}
</script>

<style scoped>
.google-map {
  width: auto;
  height: 450px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  background: gray;
  border-radius: 4px;
}
</style>
```

Lo que estoy intentando hacer ahora es añadir un evento mouseover para que cuando un usuario pase por encima del icono de una localización esta se haga más grande pero ando algo perdido acerca de como añadir el evento. Yo imagino que tengo que usar algo como esto:

```
google.maps.event.addListener(name, 'mouseover', function() {
    //FUNCION
});
```

Luego en el componente donde necesite poner el mapa solo tendría que poner:

```
<template>
   ...
   <google-map></google-map>
   ...
</template>
<script>
import GoogleMap from './GoogleMap';

export default{
    name: 'ListDetail',
    components: {
        GoogleMap,
    }
</script>
```

Alguien me puede echar una mano? Gracias y perdón si la pregunta resulta muy obvia, estoy empezando con Javascript y Vue y aún me queda por aprender.

Comment: Lo que puedes hacer  es agregar métodos que  realicen la asignación de addEventListener como en este ejemplo. https://gist.github.com/fhferreira/6b6d41884afdb3aff33326948888730d

Comment: Gracias lo he mirado por encima y creo que puede ser útil

Comment: @alwaysleam me avisas si te funciono con el ejemplo para cerrar la pregunta con la respuesta.